# Nsight Graphics Debugging "completed successfully" error

Tags: winapi, opengl, nvidia, nsight

When attempting to "Start Graphics Debugging" in Nsight for a DLL that launches an EXE, I get the following output and no other things happen:

> The operation completed successfully (System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception)

I've updated Nsight and my video drivers - still nothing.  Can't seem to find anything online about it either.

Running a GeForce GTX 480 on Windows 7.

Answer (score 0):

There are many reasons which may bring `System.ComponentModel.Win32Exeption` happen, but from your context, I am guessing you are trying to launch another process within a "launcher" process, please try this to Nsight User Setting:

- set the launcher path to "Launch External Program"
- check the checkbox named "Application is a launcher"
- set your "Working directory" to proper folder path

Be note, check the "Application is a launcher" is the key to make Nsight know the target exe is not the real target, but Nsight will prompt a dialog box to ask for some confirm.

There are also some other reason which may bring this exception happen, but need more confirm from you, for example, are you using managed code like C#? Nsight have some issue on support this kind of application.

Hope this helps

Thanks
An